# form > .panel > .panel-body > form-group content is not inside the .panel-body

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, panel

Here is my use case: I want to create panels inside a form in order to distinguish different criteria.

My problem is that when I create a `<div class="form-group">` inside my `<div class="panel-body">`, the content of the `form-group` goes out of its boundaries: in the screenshot, my checkboxes are out of the `panel-body` boundaries.

[image: checkboxes out of the <code>panel-body</code>]

Here is my DOM tree:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
```

Can somebody tells me how to do that in the good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is to add this to my CSS:

```css
.form-horizontal .panel-body .form-group {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```